# My Site Cleanup Job deleting My Site immediately

Tags: 2010, my-site, central-administration

Our current environment is *SharePoint 2010* and have My Sites enabled. The *My Site Cleanup Job* is also enabled and set to run every hour as set by default.

Once an account is deleted or deactivated within Active Directory, this correctly flags a profile for deletion and if the user had a My Site, the manager will receive a notification that it will be deleted in 14 days.

However the My Site is deleted immediately and there is no delay.

Checking in the UPSA, an account deactivated yesterday morning had their My MySite deleted this morning and is also not in the *Profiles Missing from Import* view even though the account was only missing for less than 1 day.

Disabling the My Site Cleanup Job stops this from happening, but want to fix this properly.

In case it is related, are the sync settings

**Exclusion Filter for Users**
[image]

**User Profile Incremental Synchronization**
[image]

Does anyone know why this would happen and how to resolve it?

Comment: did the manager get the notification?

Comment: Yeah, the 14 day notification goes through. If the same pattern applies as usual, they will receive the 3 day notification as well, even though it's deleted.

Comment: that's weird, I checked all the settings at my end but cant find a setting which can delete the mysite immediately.

Comment: I've scoured everything as well and it simply deletes their profile and MySite instantly.

Comment: Hi I am getting the same issue!! did you get any fix yet ?

Comment: Never found a fix unfortunately. We've moved to a fresh 2013 environment and seems to work as expected now.